# Generating simple CRUD stored procs

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, code-generation

I'm working on a project that is subject to certain corporate standards relating to SQL implementation.  Specifically, that all SQL Server content be accessed *only* via stored proc.  (No ORM or LINQ.)

80% or more of our needs can be handled through the basic CRUD (CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE) type of procedure that should be fairly simple to generate.  However, I've been unsuccessful so far in locating an existing tool that will generate these fairly simple "base" stored procedures.

So, can anyone point me to a tool that I can use to generate the bulk of my required procedures?  Preferably one that allows some customization of the process, such as wrapping the statements in a basic `BEGIN/END TRY` construct.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have visual studio then [this is the answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673563/how-do-i-generate-crud-stored-procedures-from-a-table-in-sql-server-management-s/11673757#11673757

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features#CRUD) from [Mladen Prajdić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31345/mladen-prajdic) sounds like it might fit the bill. You can customise the templates it uses.

It's well worth trying anyway for its other handy features.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm baffled as to why this didn't show up when I did a search.  I only found a couple of CodeProject articles that didn't quite fit the bill.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+generate+crud&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=uAM&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=SQL+2005+generate+crud&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&psj=1&fp=7b3e9e0669ddb0a1 - third result.

Comment: That is awesome! And it looks like it is free if you are not using SSMS 2012, I'm using 2008R2 so I am very happy (not that it is very expensive otherwise anyway).

Answer (score 3):

ssms tools pack claims to do this:  http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/ .  Example code:

```
USE [AdventureWorks];
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('[Person].[usp_AddressSelect]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP PROC [Person].[usp_AddressSelect] 
END 
GO
CREATE PROC [Person].[usp_AddressSelect] 
    @AddressID INT
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  

    BEGIN TRAN

    SELECT [AddressID], [AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [City], [StateProvinceID], [PostalCode], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate] 
    FROM   [Person].[Address] 
    WHERE  ([AddressID] = @AddressID OR @AddressID IS NULL) 

    COMMIT
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('[Person].[usp_AddressInsert]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP PROC [Person].[usp_AddressInsert] 
END 
GO
CREATE PROC [Person].[usp_AddressInsert] 
    @AddressLine1 nvarchar(60),
    @AddressLine2 nvarchar(60),
    @City nvarchar(30),
    @StateProvinceID int,
    @PostalCode nvarchar(15),
    @rowguid uniqueidentifier,
    @ModifiedDate datetime
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  

    BEGIN TRAN

    INSERT INTO [Person].[Address] ([AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [City], [StateProvinceID], [PostalCode], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate])
    SELECT @AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @City, @StateProvinceID, @PostalCode, @rowguid, @ModifiedDate

    -- Begin Return Select <- do not remove
    SELECT [AddressID], [AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [City], [StateProvinceID], [PostalCode], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate]
    FROM   [Person].[Address]
    WHERE  [AddressID] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    -- End Return Select <- do not remove

    COMMIT
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('[Person].[usp_AddressUpdate]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP PROC [Person].[usp_AddressUpdate] 
END 
GO
CREATE PROC [Person].[usp_AddressUpdate] 
    @AddressID int,
    @AddressLine1 nvarchar(60),
    @AddressLine2 nvarchar(60),
    @City nvarchar(30),
    @StateProvinceID int,
    @PostalCode nvarchar(15),
    @rowguid uniqueidentifier,
    @ModifiedDate datetime
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  

    BEGIN TRAN

    UPDATE [Person].[Address]
    SET    [AddressLine1] = @AddressLine1, [AddressLine2] = @AddressLine2, [City] = @City, [StateProvinceID] = @StateProvinceID, [PostalCode] = @PostalCode, [rowguid] = @rowguid, [ModifiedDate] = @ModifiedDate
    WHERE  [AddressID] = @AddressID

    -- Begin Return Select <- do not remove
    SELECT [AddressID], [AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [City], [StateProvinceID], [PostalCode], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate]
    FROM   [Person].[Address]
    WHERE  [AddressID] = @AddressID 
    -- End Return Select <- do not remove

    COMMIT TRAN
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('[Person].[usp_AddressDelete]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP PROC [Person].[usp_AddressDelete] 
END 
GO
CREATE PROC [Person].[usp_AddressDelete] 
    @AddressID int
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  

    BEGIN TRAN

    DELETE
    FROM   [Person].[Address]
    WHERE  [AddressID] = @AddressID

    COMMIT
GO

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```