# Generate CRUD functions for a table in PostreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am using functions to do the CRUD (insert, select, update, delete) operations on my data. Most of the time these functions do not do anything clever and I was wondering if anyone knows a tool which can generate them for me. Simple `language sql` functions would be enough. Other languages like `plpgsql` are also acceptable.

Comment: And what is so difficult about `create`, `insert`, `update`, and `delete`?  Or are you looking for an ORM interface?

Comment: Nothing difficult really, just repetitive. I'd like to use functions to keep some database logic in them but most of the time they could be generated with a simple script. I can write a script myself, not a problem but wanted to avoid reinventing the wheel if possible.

Comment: Similar question for SQLserver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673563/how-do-i-generate-crud-stored-procedures-from-a-table-in-sql-server-management-s